# Admin is showing different price to Front End

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I have set up an OpenCart store for my Australian company.

In *System>>Localisation>>Currencies* I created a new Currency for Australian Dollars with the code AUD.

[image]

Then in *System>>Settings>>Store Name>>Local* I set the Country to Australia and the Currency to AU Dollar:

[image]

But when I add a new product and set the price the price on the front end appears different. Its like the price at the back end is set in US dollars but then is adjusted to AU dollars on the front end:

**Admin:**
[image]

**Front End:**
[image]

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Make the back end use Australian Dollars instead of USD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept is $(USD) is default for admin panel so any amount you add on admin panel is in $(USD). in your contest $70 is for Drama Tas Individual Product which is USD

Now in setting `System>>Settings>>Store Name>>Local` you have set $(AUD), So in front each and every amount will be converted from `USD => AUD` by default or from USD to any other currency user selects.

In `System>>Localisation>>Currencies` you have set `1(USD) = 1.24960005(AUD)` so your product amount will be `$70(USD)*1.2496005(AUD) = $87.472035(AUD)`

Answer (score 0):

OK I took a total guess at this and it paid off. In *System>>Settings>>Store Name>>Store tab* I same the Geocode field was empty.

I pasted in my city's Long/Lat coordinates and it worked...